# Iterate on object map/list in helm template file using terraform helm release deployment

Tags: terraform, yaml, format, kubernetes-helm

I have this variable in terraform :

```
variable "users" {
  description = "List of users with their roles and databases."

  type = list(object({
    name      = string
    roles     = list(string)
    databases = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name      = "user_1"
      roles     = ["superuser", "createdb"]
      databases = ["db1", "db2"]
    },
    {
      name      = "user_2"
      roles     = ["createdb"]
      databases = ["db3"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This variable gives default values for my values.yaml file in order to set the users entry who looks like this:

```
users:
  - name: ""
    roles: []
    databases: []
```

This values.yaml file have to set my deployment.yaml like this:

```
kind: deployment
apiVersion: deployment/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.namespace }}
spec:
  ...
  users:
    user_1:
      - superuser
      - createdb
    user_2:
      - createdb
  databases:
    db_1: user_1
    db_2: user_1
    db_3: user_2
```

I have made this in my deployment.yaml file in order to range over users entries :

```
kind: deployment
apiVersion: deployment/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.namespace }}
spec:
  ...
  users:
  {{- range .Values.users }}
    {{ .name }}:
    {{- range .roles }}
    - {{ . }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  databases:
  {{- range .Values.users }}
  {{- $currentUser := . }}
  {{- range $currentUser.databases }}
    {{ . }}: {{ $currentUser.name }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

This is how I need the values from my terraform variable var.users have to be.

In my terraform code, I have made this :

```
resource "helm_release" "my_release" {
  name       = "${var.namespace}-my-release"
  repository = "${path.module}/helm"
  ...

  set {
    name = "users"
    value = replace(yamlencode([
      for user in var.users : {
        name      = user.name
        roles     = tolist(user.roles)
        databases = tolist(user.databases)
      }
    ]), "\"", "")
  }
```

Using this terraform code provides this result :

```
<<EOT
- name: user_1
  roles:
  - superuser
  - createdb
- name: user_2
  roles:
  - createdb

EOT
```

But I have this error :

```
error running dry run for a diff: template: deployment.yaml:28:19: executing "deployment.yaml" at <.Values.users>: range can't iterate over - databases:
│   - db1
│   - db2
│   name: user_1
│   roles:
│   - superuser
│   - createdb
│ - databases:
│   - db3
│   name: user_2
│   roles:
│   - createdb
```

I test my code using the online tool `helm-playground.com` [here](https://helm-playground.com/#t=ATCuGcFMCdwLgFAgN7ILTGgQwHYHNJgA6ANSwBtRJwiIZxgBfRpEYVYnLAW0OcTbt0mXAWLQA9uWpMWgjByKzWKYZBwATZaozqtzVhqwAXLACMsUeK1QZs%2BQqQpUadWNqEYAJAGNQ0aHVjAFUoaGA4AF5iD1sRB2Bff0CcELCiI1MLKw9VGP4hRL8AoNCYIi5eWLVNat1a5iA&v=LQhQFcGcFMCdIFygATOMgdgQwLbQclHAPoCMKqysA9gDbSIWrqTgAOcRsTayAxrGhYALtAAmAIx5iRWCVhiJkPdJLIrkagEwV02PAS7EdlKnQYENAoaMnTZ8xZdOqJxAMxA) and it seems that my range iteration is good.

How to format or iterate correctly on the object users ?

Comment: Check the documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release and note you would want to use the `set_list` block, and then convert the `object` to a JSON format string with escaped characters. It is rather onerous, and so you may want to set values differently.

Comment: It seems that what you are generating here is not a YAML file directly, but rather a [Go template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) that would generate one. Terraform's `yamlencode` function is for generating concrete YAML documents, not for generating Go templates that generate YAML documents. Are you trying to use Terraform to generate something equivalent to what that Go template would've generated, or are you just trying to parse the Go template to the Helm provider verbatim, so that Helm can be the one to render the template?

Comment: @MartinAtkins I have updated my initial post in order to better explain my intention and give my recent error

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard the `set_list` block is not helpful in my case. thank you for your comment

Comment: Now that I understand the problem a little better, unfortunately I concur with @MatthewSchuchard that `set_list` seems to be the answer here, unless the template language in Helm has a way to decode a YAML document and then iterate over the decoded result. Currently you are trying to iterate over a string containing YAML, which isn't supported in Helm's template language.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Helm templating is just Go template+Sprig, and so you almost certainly would know its capabilities already with your experience

Comment: While Helm is indeed using Go templates, there are two important Helm-specific details here: exactly what data is Helm exposing to the template, and what functions Helm is making available for use in the template. With your current configuration Helm is exposing a string containing YAML to the template. With `set_list` it would presumably expose a Go slice, which you could then use with `range`. Helm might also offer a custom YAML decoding directive/function, which might therefore let you decode the current YAML string and then iterate over its result. All of those are Helm-specific, though.

Comment: In the Helm docs I see [Type Conversion Functions](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions), which lists `fromYamlArray` as an available function, so that's one possible way to convert from your YAML string to something that would work with `range`.